# Is there a way to modify content being pasted in textAngular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex, textangular

When someone pastes content copied from a website or even a word document, textAngular adds additional break `<br>` tags before and after the content.

I'm using textAngular like this:

```
<text-angular name="summary" ng-model="summary" ta-paste="trimTags($html)" required>
</text-angular>
```

What I'd like to do is somehow trim the leading and trailing `<br>` tags.

The first approach I tried was writing a regex that will trim 2 leading and trailing `<br>` tags.

```
/(\<br\s*\/\>)(\<\/?body\>)(\<br\s*\/\>)/g
```

This works, but the changes are NOT reflected in the text presented. Is there a way to pass this `$html` being pasted and reflect the changes after modifying it?

Alternatively, I tried the ng-change approach, with no luck since it pastes the actual code, sometimes mixing `<br>` and `<p>` tags it adds.

Another problem is that, you could paste something in the middle of the text, which makes detecting changes difficult and time consuming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A silly overlook, if anyone has trouble with this, use the `ta-paste` and the regex from the question, and after modifying the content simply return it.

```
$scope.trimTags = function(content){
    //process the content
    return content;
};
```